# How to use full power of computer to run a code?

Tags: python, math

I want to run a code with 10e+15 simulations,
Is it possible to run?

```
def simulate_stock_price(days, current_price):
    if days == 0:
        return current_price > 150

    coin_flip = random.choice(['Heads', 'Tails'])
    dice_roll = random.randint(1, 6)
    
    if coin_flip == 'Heads':
        current_price += dice_roll
    else:
        current_price -= dice_roll

    return simulate_stock_price(days - 1, current_price)

def calculate_probability(num_simulations, days):
    num_successful_simulations = 0
    for _ in range(num_simulations):
        if simulate_stock_price(days, 100):
            num_successful_simulations += 1

    return num_successful_simulations / num_simulations

num_simulations = 10e+15
days = 10

probability = calculate_probability(num_simulations, days)
print(f"Estimated probability after {days} days: {probability:.4f}")
```

How I can run this code because VS code is taking decades to run.

I have try to run this in online python complier like programiz but filed. So, I finding how to run this code directly in my pc with my pc's full power.

Comment: How many cores does your computer have? If it has `n` cores, then `multiprocessing` *could* reduce the time taken by `n` times. Not much if it is already taking `"decades to run"`

Comment: `coin_flip` and `dice_roll` checks can be removed if you use: `current_price += np.random.choice([-1, 1]) * np.random.randint(1, 6)`

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Your "simulation" and the result for probability basically depend only on the random function. I'm pretty sure that Python's random function generates uniformly distributed random numbers if it is called often enough. The result for your probability should be quite the same, no matter if you call your simulation 1000 times, 1 million times of 10e+15 times.

Comment: I couldn't resist... Without numpy but with multiprocessing of pure Python code optimised to the best of my ability I calculate that on Apple Silicon (M2), running 10 quadrillion simulations would take ~12 years

Comment: @Codist I don't understand your comment that the probability will always be zero, could you give more details? For instance, getting 10 "Heads" and then 10 sixes allows the price to fulfill the condition, and will mathematically happen with a probability of (1/12)^10. Does something about python's rng make that impossible?

Comment: @Seon OK - So it's theoretically possible. I will delete my erroneous comment. When you've written some code that produces the desired result, please let us know what parameters you used and how long your program ran for

Comment: @Codist sure! See my answer below - running 1e8 simulations (which takes around 10s on my laptop) gave a probability of  `1.47e-6`, which is reasonably close to the theoretical value of around `1.4564e-6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by the other answers already, `10e15` is a ridiculously high number.
I'd also add that this is a problem you should probably be solving using math, not simulations.

Should you still want to simulate your scenario, here's some vectorized numpy code that will be much faster at it than your current implementation:

```py
import numpy as np

days = 10
n_sim = int(1e8)

start_price = 100
threshold_price = 150

dice_roll = np.random.randint(low=1, high=7, size=(n_sim, days), dtype=np.int8)  # 1-6
coin_flip = (
    np.random.randint(0, 2, (n_sim, days), dtype=np.int8)
) * 2 - 1  # -1 or 1 with a probability of 0.5

final_price = start_price + (dice_roll * coin_flip).sum(-1)
probability = (final_price > threshold_price).mean()

print(
    f"Estimated probability after {days} days over {n_sim} simulations: {probability}"
)
```

This runs in ~10s and gives a solution that's reasonably close to the theoretical value, detailed in the edit below.

---

**Edit with exact solution**:
What you're doing here is sampling 10 numbers uniformly at random from `{-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`, and calculating whether their sum is strictly greater than 50.
We can calculate that probability exactly by generating all possible combinations of size 10 of those numbers, and counting how many sum to a number greater than 50.

Doing so in python would be excessively slow, so we write some very crude c++ code to do the job:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint64_t tot_num = 0;
    uint64_t num_valid = 0;

    int roll[12] = {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int sum;
    std::cout << "Starting..." << std::endl;
    for (int day0 = 0; day0 < 12; day0++)
    {
        for (int day1 = 0; day1 < 12; day1++)
        {
            for (int day2 = 0; day2 < 12; day2++)
            {
                for (int day3 = 0; day3 < 12; day3++)
                {
                    for (int day4 = 0; day4 < 12; day4++)
                    {
                        for (int day5 = 0; day5 < 12; day5++)
                        {
                            for (int day6 = 0; day6 < 12; day6++)
                            {
                                for (int day7 = 0; day7 < 12; day7++)
                                {
                                    for (int day8 = 0; day8 < 12; day8++)
                                    {
                                        for (int day9 = 0; day9 < 12; day9++)
                                        {
                                            sum = roll[day0] + roll[day1] + roll[day2] + roll[day3] + roll[day4] + roll[day5] + roll[day6] + roll[day7] + roll[day8] + roll[day9];
                                            if (sum > 50)
                                            {
                                                num_valid++;
                                            }
                                            tot_num++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << num_valid << std::endl;
    std::cout << tot_num << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This runs in a few seconds, and shows that `90178` of the `12^10 = 61917364224` possible draws sum to a number strictly greater than 50.
The exact probability you're looking for is therefore `90178/61917364224`, or around `1.45e-6`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: Everything you do 10e15 times on a computer takes a good time. It's a very huge number... So don't expect it to be done in a second.

E.g.: If your target is 1h, then you need to run 2.77e12 simulations per second, so you have 3.6*10^13 seconds per simulation = 0.36 picoseconds.

To your question:

1. You could optimize your code by vectorization using [numpy](https://numpy.org/).
2. You can use Pythons [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).
3. If you run your code in VS it will always use your local machine. So it is just a lack of (single core) CPU power which can be solved with 1. & 2.

Answer (score 3):

10e15 is way to much.
Even if you used 8 cores and executed 4.5e9 loops on each core every second, it would still take more than 3 days. And that is a very VERY generous calculation. Your CPU has to do other stuff, you won't get close to 4.5e9 loops each second.

Why don't you try to start from 10e5 and see how long it takes. Then you can estimate a sensible range.

You can try using numba to precompile the code and use numpy vectorized functions.